# Populate a SQL table with data

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am wondering if there is any alternative to copy-paste for populating a table?
I have a set of many sentences and each sentence has to be a record in a table.

Is there any way (script?) to get the data into th table without having to copypaste each item into an INSERT statement? Maybe a loop that goes line buy line from a varchar variable and uses it in the INSERT statement?

I was researching this question but have not come up with any solutions...

Comment: What specifically have you researched or tried so far?

Comment: loops, counting lines... no luck so far - probably was not looking very well..

Comment: Any language capable of reading files and interfacing with sql-server 2008 would be able to manage this. However, I'm not aware of any application that will do exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: It would not have been a problem if I had VS, however, for now I do not have access to it (soon..). I am trying to accomplish this via pure SQL

Comment: There are [hundreds of questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql-server+import+data) on this site about importing data into SQL Server. It would help if you can explain what format the data is in (CSV, plain text, Excel, ...?), what your target table looks like (the `CREATE TABLE` definition), if you need to add values for columns not included in the source file etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy the data in to CSV File and import the CSV file using import flat file option in Management studio. You can map columns as required.

Comment: Where do I find this option?

Comment: Assuming you have the management studio , you can find the 'Import Data' option upon right clicking on database. Also, for alternative , see this : http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/

Comment: I already tried bulk but I do not have permission to use it. apparently, Import is also blocked because I do not see it there... Thank you, anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802%28v=sql.100%29) via Command-Shell.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know sql-server-2008 (is that Microsoft?), but I'm very confident that the `COPY` instruction also exists in that server. If so, I guess something along these lines works:

```
COPY tablename FROM `/some/file/on/your/disk` WITH DELIMITER ';'
```

For PostgreSQL this is the documentation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: MS SQL Server 2008 R2 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23650